# Get original Laravel Eloquent model on update

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following code where I fire an event comparing two versions of the same model.
I worked around it by manually setting a "dirty" attribute.
However, is there a way to fetch the whole original model on `updated` event?

```
class NovaSubscriptionObserver
{
    public function updated(Subscription $subscription): void
    {
        if ($subscription->isDirty('price_id')) {
            $oldSubscription = $subscription;
            $oldSubscription->price_id = $subscription->getOriginal('price_id');
            SubscriptionCreatedOrUpdatedEvent::dispatch($subscription, $oldSubscription);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$originalModel = $subscription->fresh();
```

Comment: You probably mean doing it on `updating` event?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$orignalColumns = $subscription->getOriginal();
```

This will return the column values that your model had when it was first loaded from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$orignalColumns = $subscription->getRawOriginal();
```

This will fetch the model's raw original attribute values.